# Reading python serial data without new line

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am reading serial port data in python. The data does not have newline, so I am receiving data continuously. The data packet has a termination with '|'. I want to read data continuously and print it on newline after '|'

My current data looks like this (highlighted fields are data of my interest in each packet, how shall I extract it and plot )

> b'\x01\x063\x011;790.10,3.73,203.45;0.00;28|1;503.36,2.88,129.87;2.00;28|1;1.00,1.60,0.23;4.00;28|1;167.10,1.13,44.98;6.00;28|1;0.07,0.34,2.02;8.00;28|1;100.44,1.04,26.24;10.00;28|1;0.33,0.89,1.65;12.00;28|1;71.72,0.13,19.10;14.00;28|1;0.07,0.41,1.76;16.00;28|1;55.70,0.08,14.89;18.00;28|1;0.19,0.61,2.07;20.00;28|1;45.84,0.46,11.70;22.00;28|1;0.07,0.44,1.76;24.00;28|1;38.87,0.53,9.90;26.00;28|1;0.12,0.11,1.62;28.00;28|1;33.65,0.26,8.57;30.00;28|1;0.07,0.11,1.58;32.00;28|1;29.80,0.36,7.51;34.00;28|1;0.09,0.37,1.48;36.00;28|1;26.65,0.17,6.80;38.00;28|1;0.07,0.28,1.43;40.00;28|1;24.07,0.11,6.32;42.00;28|1;0.06,0.14,1.66;44.00;28|1;22.11,0.09,5.65;46.00;28|1;0.07,0.15,1.66;48.00;28|1;20.41,0.22,5.13;50.00;28|1;0.05,0.08,1.61;52.00;28|1;18.93,0.05,4.80;54.00;28|1;0.06,0.12,1.77;56.00;28|1;17.74,0.14,4.24;58.00;28|1;0.03,0.04,1.57;60.00;28|1;16.61,0.06,4.03;62.00;28|1;0.06,0.07,1.55;64.00;28|1;15.59,0.14,3.86;66.00;28|1;0.02,0.11,1.68;68.00;28|1;14.78,0.12,3.49;70.00;28|1;0.06,0.18,1.57;72.00;28|1;14.03,0.05,3.39;74.00;28|1;0.01,0.09,1.67;76.00;28|1;13.35,0.04,3.15;78.00;28|1;0.05,0.14,1.72;80.00;28|1;12.81,0.18,2.85;82.00;28|1;0.00,0.10,1.60;84.00;28|1;12.26,0.16,2.75;86.00;28|1;0.05,0.07,1.61;88.00;28|1;11.73,0.08,2.58;90.00;28|1;0.01,0.08,1.58;92.00;28|1;11.31,0.10,2.46;94.00;28|1;0.04,0.16,1.54;96.00;28|1;10.87,0.07,2.40;98.00;28|1;0.01,0.08,1.57;100.00;28|1;10.48,0.06,2.32;102.00;28|1;0.04,0.06,1.66;104.00;28|1;10.19,0.06,2.15;106.00;28|1;0.02,0.03,1.64;108.00;28|1;9.87,0.09,2.05;110.00;28|1;0.03,0.07,1.65;112.00;28|1;9.57,0.02,1.94;114.00;28|1;0.02,0.04,1.69;116.00;28|1;9.33,0.09,1.75;118.00;28|1;0.03,0.04,1.57;120.00;28|1;9.05,0.03,1.75;122.00;28|1;0.02,0.02,1.61;124.00;28|1;8.79,0.08,1.68;126.00;28|1;0.02,0.10,1.65;128.00;28|1;8.61,0.05,1.55;130.00;28|1;0.03,0.11,1.58;132.00;28|1;8.40,0.06,1.56;134.00;28|1;0.02,0.04,1.67;136.00;28|1;8.22,0.05,1.42;138.00;28|1;0.03,0.07,1.65;140.00;28|1;8.08,0.13,1.31;142.00;28|1;0.01,0.07,1.59;144.00;28|1;7.90,0.08,1.30;146.00;28|1;0.03,0.06,1.62;148.00;28|1;7.73,0.03,1.20;150.00;28|1;0.01,0.07,1.58;152.00;28|1;7.60,0.04,1.17;154.00;28|1;0.03,0.10,1.57;156.00;28|1;7.45,0.07,1.16;158.00;28|1;0.01,0.02,1.62;160.00;28|1;7.33,0.04,1.10;162.00;28|1;0.03,0.04,1.65;164.00;28|1;7.26,0.05,1.01;166.00;28|1;0.00,0.01,1.64;168.00;28|1;7.14,0.04,0.96;170.00;28|1;0.03,0.05,1.66;172.00;28|1;7.03,0.05,0.88;174.00;28|1;0.00,0.02,1.65;176.00;28|1;6.95,0.07,0.78;178.00;28|1;0.03,0.05,1.57;180.00;28|1;6.84,0.02,0.81;182.00;28|1;0.01,0.03,1.62;184.00;28|1;6.75,0.04,0.74;186.00;28|1;0.03,0.09,1.62;188.00;28|1;6.71,0.06,0.68;190.00;28|1;0.01,0.07,1.59;192.00;28|1;6.64,0.06,0.70;194.00;28|1;0.02,0.02,1.67;196.00;28|1;6.58,0.06,0.57;198.00;28|1;0.01,0.04,1.62;200.00;28|1;6.54,0.10,0.53;202.00;28|1;0.02,0.08,1.59;204.00;28|1;6.46,0.04,0.52;206.00;28|1;0.02,0.06,1.62;208.00;28|1;6.40,0.01,0.45;210.00;28|1;0.02,0.06,1.58;212.00;28|1;6.37,0.03,0.45;214.00;28|1;0.02,0.06,1.60;216.00;28|1;6.32,0.07,0.43;218.00;28|1;0.02,0.01,1.64;220.00;28|1;6.29,0.02,0.36;222.00;28|1;0.02,0.03,1.65;224.00;28|1;6.29,0.05,0.31;226.00;28|1;0.01,0.02,1.64;228.00;28|1;6.24,0.01,0.26;230.00;28|1;0.02,0.04,1.66;232.00;28|1;6.21,0.06,0.18;234.00;28|1;0.01,0.03,1.62;236.00;28|1;6.20,0.05,0.14;238.00;28|1;0.02,0.06,1.57;240.00;28|1;6.16,0.01,0.16;242.00;28|1;0.01,0.04,1.62;244.00;28|1;6.16,0.02,0.09;246.00;28|1;0.02,0.09,1.60;248.00;28|1;6.18,0.07,0.09;250.00;28|1;0.00,0.04,1.60;252.00;28|1;6.17,0.06,0.08;254.00;28|DATAEND|

## I am currenlty reading 3480 bytes. but want to read data continuously

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
buff = list()
values = bytearray([1,6,51,1])   # serial port command to read serial data
#print(type(values))
ser.write(values)


while True:
    
    s = ser.read(3480)
    print(s)
```

I want to separate all fields and print the data that is highlighted

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of read_until which allows you to define the character which works like a newline (LF is the default value). The call signature is read_until(expected=LF, size=None). For details consult https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html . Alternatively you could read everything which is available and use a regular expression to find the single packages and extract the fields. This can be done by re.find_iter.